# Convert typed array to utf8 string

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, utf-8

I'm trying to create an equivalent method of `crypto.randomBytes` based on `crypto.getRandomValues` on browsers. How can I encode the cryptographically random values generated from `crypto.getRandomValues` to utf8?

Comment: Random bytes usually returns an array of byte, why do you want a *string* ?

Comment: @AlexK. I'm using an external password hashing library that only accepts string values. BTW, since string value is so unusual, why does `crypto.randomBytes` generates a string one instead of a typed array?